# Retrieve data from a mountable partition refusing `cp` but allowing `dd`

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, dd, testdisk, bad-blocks

Recently, my internal drive failed after a manual reboot and I would like to retrieve the data before changing it. My computer is a Macbook Pro mid-2012 and the drive is formatted as HFS+. (From my point of view, the problem is hardware related and so not specific to the Apple world, so I post here rather than on apple.stackexchange but feel free to migrate it if necessary.)

The usual `dd` cloning is not an option : it is a 500GB drive and for some reason the rate of the copy is 20KB/s (well at least with `bs=512` which I have seen to be recommended when dealing with hard drives), meaning it would take approximately 6000 hours to get the job done...

Mounting the partition and using `cp` is not either : when I try this, I get the message

```
cp : Input/output error
```

Also, it might be important to say that I can't mount the partition in a traditionnal way. It gets mounted only at start in recovery mode, or after running an analysis with TestDisk when booting from an external drive.

From the analysis with TestDisk (which reveal no error), I think that the filesystem is fine and I am more inclined to think that the drive has bad blocks (hence physically damaged, right?). Plus, when I tried `fsck_hfs`, it sure did not work but the error seemed unrelated to filesystem : it said

```
could not get Block 2, not a MDB sector
[...]
volumeType is 0
```

(If needed, I can rerun it to paste the entire log.)

But I still can use `dd` on individual files (I don't need all the data) when the partition is mounted. Is there any script/software that use `dd` internally to copy the content of entire directories? I really don't want to actually write a `dd` command on hundred of files...

Or does anyone have a better idea to get a little of those data back ?

Comment: What OS are you using to `dd` the disk?

Comment: @DanielB OS X. I tried to boot on a Ubuntu live usb key without any luck, so I installed OS X on an external drive to get some tools (also `dd` is actually avaible on the recovery system).

Comment: `dd` is very slow when using `/dev/diskX`. Instead, use large block sizes (≥1 MiB) and `/dev/rdiskX`. Also, make (very!) sure no filesystem is mounted from the disk/partition you’re cloning.

Comment: @DanielB Yes I read that about the raw version of the disk, so I currently run a `dd` with `rdisk` instead of `disk` with a block size of 20MB and it should not take more than 10 or 12 hours. For the potentially mounted partitions, I actually am cloning a unique partition and `dd` automatically denies you permission if it is mounted.

Answer (score 1):

Using `dd` with `bs=512` can really cripple speeds, I'm imagining it's like trying to run a mile but taking 1 inch steps. Using a bigger value like `bs=10M` or bigger should be a lot better.

Anyway, files are probably not all contiguous so trying to cut out just the right parts of the drive with `dd` won't work for every file, and (probably, not too sure how HFS works) wouldn't get you filenames either. A better idea would be trying a program that can copy files off of partitions that may have problems, using:

- `testdisk` can look at files (including recently deleted files) for many filesystems and copy them off of a partition. It's sister program `photorec` can search through a raw drive (or drive image) and copy out files too, but usually without their original names.
- But the best might be using `gddrescue` to make a copy of the readable parts of the drive, it's supposed to be an expert at data recovery with failing drives, it can skip over parts that fail a read, and once it's gotten all the "easy" parts you can try again for the "hard" parts that may or may not read but take a long time. Then you could properly attempt filesystem checking/fixing and data carving (photorec) without worrying about further drive damage or sudden failure.

  - See the [GNU ddrescue Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html) and there are some guides available on the web (but I'm more apt to read the fine manual first).

Comment: Thanks for the advise. Since my question, I actually ran a `dd` clone with `bs=20m` and (still running), it should be finished by tonight. Still, I don't think it is gonna do any good as I continuously see input/output error on the screen (so I imagine `dd` writes a lot of zeros in my image...). I tried testdisk but you can't look inside and copy for HFS partitions. I tried photorec which wanted to take something like 3000 hours to get my files. Finally, I heard of GNU ddrescue and it is my next step if `dd` fails. Thanks for the advices !